# Coding Mastermind in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I was wondering how to code the game, [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)), in Java, but with things up a notch (I want to inform the user not only how many pegs they got right or wrong, but also how many they guessed correctly in the **wrong slots**).

For instance, say the RNG answer of 5 digits of numbers 1-6 is:

22354

... and the user's guess is:

32624

Resulting in:

- two guessed correctly (2 and 4)
- two guessed partially correct (2 and 3)
- one guessed incorrectly (6).

Here's my code for informing the user what they got correct:

```
String answer = "22354";
String guess = "32624";
int correctPegs = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    char a = answer.charAt(i);
    char g = guess.charAt(i);

    if (a == g) {
        correctPegs++;
    }
}

System.out.println(correctPegs);
```

**How would I find the partially correct ones?**

... and for calculating how many the user guessed incorrectly, I was thinking of using basic algebra to find the remaining characters **after** finding the correct and partially correct ones.

Comment: Don't overthink. Write down the rules; and implement them in the most simply way possible. First solve the problem at all; before thinking about optimizations. And when I look at how your count your own example; I am not so sure if you really got all the rules right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put '0' into the strings where they match. Then for every char that is not a zero, I would look through the answer string again. If any character in the answer string matches, I would make them both zero, and increment outOfPlacePegs.

This guards against two corner cases I am assuming you do not want:

One is when you have '323' as the answer and '223' as the input. You don't want the first '2' to be recorded as out of place.

Second is when you have '223' as the answer and '442' as the input. You don't want this recorded as two numbers out of place.